# IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am new to Android and am trying to create a LinearLayout and add TextViews to it.

```
private TextView listOfInstalledApplicationsText;
private TextView listOfInstalledPackagesText;
private TextView scrollAppsView;
private ArrayList<CharSequence> installedApplications;
private ArrayList<CharSequence> installedPackages;
private LinearLayout layout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vib_app_assigment);

    listOfInstalledApplicationsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.installedAppsView);
    listOfInstalledPackagesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.installedPackagesView);
    layout = findViewById(R.id.dropDownMenuLayout);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );



    installedApplications = this.getApplicationNames();
    installedPackages = this.getPackageNames();

    scrollAppsView = findViewById(R.id.scrollAppNamesView);

    layout.addView(scrollAppsView);

}
```

Unfortunately, on the last line I get the following error:
"IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: where are you getting this from ? : scrollAppsView = findViewById(R.id.scrollAppNamesView);

Comment: Why do you want to add the `scrollAppsView` to the `layout` when are already both in your Activity layout?

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says...A view cannot be added more than once. Your view is defined in your xml of the activity and therefore has a parent. The ViewGroup in which you wrote it. If for some reason you want to move that view to another ViewGroup then you have to remove it first by calling

```
 ((ViewGroup)scrollAppsView.getParent()).removeView(scrollAppsView);
```

However (even though I don't know what you are trying to do) I 'm pretty sure that you are approaching this the wrong way. If you have included your TextViews in your xml there is no reason to add them again programmaticaly. They are allready added.